# SQL Server Reporting Services Adjust Chart boundaries and list series by financial year

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like some help with SSRS. I'm charting some data, but I'd like to show the results by financial year. The current setup by calendar is not really useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your question it is not really clear what kind of help do you need. Can you provide some additional information on your problem? Like what's your Datesets like, what data set fields do you pass and perhaps links on screenshots of the problematic areas or on the results you are not happy with. Even better if you can provide a link to a sample that shows what kind of result are you trying to achieve. Regards,<br/>
Ramzy!

Comment: Add some details on how it is and how you want by adding some examples/screenshots.

Comment: I am using a line graph. Currently data is charted by month and year. The graph starts at January and ends in December. I want the graph x-axis to start at July and end in June.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Xe5.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rawfX.png

Comment: The first picture above shows what the chart looks like at the moment.

The second image shows what I want my charts to look like. They are run by financial year June to July, with the year series altered accordingly.

Comment: @Mangaman hey, in my projects I use third party control, so I'm not so familiar with the standard control, but logically this should be possible to achieve without any other add-ins, by setting parameters for the "Start" and "End" date and configuring the series date by the parameters. Anyway as I'm not really able to guide you in this process step by step, I would suggest you to edit your question and add the information from your comments under "**Edited:**" marker, so you can attract more people to look at it and get a response quicker.